# How to pass datasource to second View Controller? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, model

So I have a dataModel that pulls Arrays from a plist using my datasource class. In my view controller I call the datasource class with

```
let dataSource = DataSource()
```

and then I grab values from the array with

```
abilities = dataSource.ability[monster.ability! + 2]
```

My issue is when I grab the `Datasource` from the second `Viewcontroller`, there is a 2-4 second delay during the segue transition. How can I pass the datasource over the second `viewcontroller`, so i can read the values, without having to call `let dataSource = DataSource()` from within the second view controller?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to handle passing information from one view controller to another.

However for your scenario I would recommend to create an array property in your second view controller that will hold your Datasource, but only by passing it from your first view controller by calling the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method.

Here is an example of how I passed simple data to another view controller, pretty much a Master-Detail setup:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? DetailNoteViewController

    if segue.identifier == "toNoteDetailView" {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }

        let note = self.notes[indexPath.row]
        destinationViewController?.note = note
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried what you said. It seems sound but I've run into an issue. I can't use the identifier `[indexPath.Row]` in the segue. Should I move the if statement to `didSelectItemAt`?

Comment: you might want to edit your answer with a code snippet..[indexPath.row] is used to get the position of the object in the array corresponding to the tableView so that it can pass the object to the second view controller